# Understanding argument unpacking in python

Tags: python, python-3.9

This is more of a curiosity rather than a problem. Playing around with double pointers I ended up with this chunk of code.

```
def mimic(trigger, **some_dict):
    print(trigger)
    print(some_dict)

mydict = {}
(look, dict2) = ('copy me', {'some':20})
mydict['args2'] = {'triggers': look}
mimic(**mydict['args2'])
```

Its output is:

```
copy me
{}
```

Now I am confused on why the variable `trigger` from `mimic()` argument takes its value from the dictionary `mydict` which looks like:

```
{'args2': {'trigger': 'copy me'}}
```

If I change one of the `triggers` naming, I get an error that my calling of `mimic()` needs 1 more argument. This is the way I expected for it to be behaving in the first place, wanting 2 arguments. This code:

```
def mimic(trigger, **some_dict):
    print(trigger)
    print(some_dict)

mydict = {}
(look, dict2) = ('copy me', {'some':20})
mydict['args2'] = {'triggerB': look}  #Changed here added a 'B'
mimic(1, **mydict['args2'])
```

Prints this:

```
1
{'triggerB': 'copy me'}
```

So now I notice that before the dictionary inside `mydict['args2']` has been taken out.
Why this happens? I am working in VScode with python 3.9.13. Is it going to happen with any other IDE too?

Comment: ** is called argument unpacking, there is no analogy with double pointers (Python is not C)

Comment: Unless explicitly specified as a positional-only or keyword-only argument, every argument of a function can be fulfilled as either a positional or a keyword argument. The `trigger` argument in the first case is passed as a keyword argument after the dict value of `mydict['args2']` is unpacked.

Comment: Title change @wim.

Comment: Thank you @blhsing, I am going to read more about positional arguments.